# how to show loader before vimeo video in iframe start playing

Tags: video, iframe, vimeo

I have iframe vimeo video in my website. It's playing well but before the video starts playing there is a blank with title and description of video coming. I want to show some loader or vimeo video image before the video starts playing. After the video starts playing the loader/image will be hidden. Is there any way to do it ? I googled for api also but to no avail.
Any help/suggestion are welcome. Thank you in advance.